# How to create a ROS package using the Oculus SDK

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am currently working on a project to make a ROS package for the oculus rift dK2 using the SDK on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 since i can't find any that works on ROS Indigo. Can anyone please explain to me the process or how can i make a ros package myself.

Thanks all,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224683/how-to-create-a-ros-package-using-the-oculus-sdk/) by [admalkhaja](https://answers.ros.org/users/25679/admalkhaja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you have ros installed and sourced (source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash -> replace indigo with your ros distribution)
then simply using catkin_create_pkg should be sufficient, however it takes arguments:

catkin_create_pkg ros_dependency1 ros_dependecy2 name_of_my_package

This macro will create a template package for you with all required dependencies, package structure and ready for you
to fill in the details.

please check also http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage     for a more detailed explanation on how to create a package.

Example:

if your node is going to be on python perhaps the command will look like this:

catkin_create_pkg rospy my_ros_pkg

if your node is on c++:

catkin_create_pkg roscpp my_ros_pkg

PD: you might want to check https://github.com/OTL/oculus    as they have something similar to what you want to do

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0